# How do i change the vowels to the next consonants and consonants to the next vowel in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Ok so I need to turn vowels in a word into the next consonant and the consonants into vowels.
example:-orange gives the output as puboif
I have got it till "consonants to the next vowel", what more do i add to do the 2nd half of the problem i.e. vowel to consonant?
i am kinda new to this any help will be really appreciated
this is what i have tried by the way.

```
#Your code below
def replaceconsonants(s): 
#idk y this long chain of vowels is here but it wont work without them for some reason.
    vowel="aaaeeeeiiiiioooooooouuuuuuu"
    for i in range (0,len(s)):
        s=s.replace(s[i],vowel[ord(s[i])-97])
    return s
s=input()
print(replaceconsonants(s))
```

Comment: Please add some comments to your code to better understand it. The long chain of vowels is confusing, so is the loop after it. Please describe your intentions in human language. 

And add an example of what you enter and what you want to get.

Comment: thanks you! i fixed it to better understand it i guess?

Comment: I can tell you why the long string is here. In `vowel[ord(s[i])-97]`, `ord(s[i])` lies between 97 (for “a”) and 122 (for “z”). Subtract 97, and you get numbers 0 to 25. That's why your `vowels` should be at least 26 characters long. It enumerates the vowels of the English alphabet and repeats them until a next vowel is reached. So, you replace every single character of `s[i]` (in a weird way) with a vowel that follows it in the alphabet. Is that what you're trying to achieve? Then just do `s = s[:i] + vowel[ord(s[i]) - 97] + s[i+1:]`. BTW, you miss an “a” and an “i” and have 2 extra “o”s.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that turns “orange” into “puboif” as requested. Note that it works only on lower-case characters of the English alphabet.

```py
def spam(s: str) -> str:
    i: int

    # note: here, you have only lower-case English vowels
    vowels: str = 'aeiou'
    # consonants are essentially set(alphabet) - set(vowels);
    # calculate consonants from it
    consonants: list[str] = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1) if chr(i) not in vowels]

    # calculate a consonant which follows a vowel
    next_consonants: list[str] = []
    for v in vowels:
        i = 0
        while (next_consonant := chr(ord(v) + i)) in vowels:
            i += 1
        next_consonants.append(next_consonant)

    # calculate a vowel which follows a consonant
    next_vowels: list[str] = []
    for c in consonants:
        i = 0
        while (next_vowel := chr(ord(c) + i)) in consonants:
            i += 1
            if next_vowel == 'z':  # end of the alphabet
                next_vowel = 'a'
                break
        next_vowels.append(next_vowel)

    # compose a new string
    result: str = ''
    for c in s:
        if c in vowels:
            result += next_consonants[vowels.index(c)]
        elif c in consonants:
            result += next_vowels[consonants.index(c)]
        else:
            result += c

    return result


print(spam('orange'))
```